# SQL Group column data from joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, rdbms

I need some help with writing SQL query.

I've data in the following format coming from a query returned by joining multiple tables.

```
CustID  Name    AccNo       Bank
------  ----    -----       -----
 1      Varun   9848032919    CB
 1      Varun   9998887771   COB
 1      Varun   9988776655    CB
 2      Lokesh  9876543210   COB
 2      Lokesh  9282726252    CB
 3      aaaa    9181716151   COB
```

I would like the data to be formatted as below so that it would be easy to load into Crystal reports.

```
CustID  Name               AccNo                      Bank
------  ----               -----                      -----
  1     Varun   9848032919,9998887771,9988776655      CB,COB,CB
  2     Lokesh  9876543210,9282726252                 COB,CB
  3     aaaa    9181716151                            COB
```

I've looked at other answers which suggest using STUFF, XML PATH() but they are applicable only if data comes from one table. In my scenario data is retrieved by joining multiple tables.

May I know how to group by `CustID` and concatenate data in other columns as I desire?

Thanks a lot for your time!!!

EDIT: I'm looking for a SQL Server 2005 version answer

Comment: Did you have time to take a look at my answer? I think it should work also in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the query inside a `CTE`, then apply `FOR XML PATH` on this `CTE` like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  ... your query here
)
SELECT C.CustID, MAX(Name),
       STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + + CAST(AccNo AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
          FROM CTE 
          WHERE (CustID = C.CustID) 
          FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
       ,1,2,'') AS AccNo,
        STUFF((
           SELECT ', ' + + CAST(Bank AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
           FROM CTE 
           WHERE (CustID = C.CustID) 
           FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2,'') AS Bank
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.CustID
```

Comment: Actually, I do not have exact data with me to test this on. I'll have to test this in my workplace. As I asked, I will put the resulting data into Crystal Report and I'm worried about CTE's scope.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, I've tested this in my actual data and happy to say that your approach works. I have a little complicated req where I should allow only last 4 characters from Account number column. I've added a case statement and checking whether the length is >4 and return only the last 4 charcters but I recieve syntax errors. Can you explain where to place the case statement?

Comment: never mind. I got it working after some googling. Thank you very much for taking your time in creating this script. I currently have no issues with running this query inside Management Studio. I'm yet to populate data in crystal reports.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the select makes it look like a simple table. You can apply the logic on the result.
Like

```
Select a.* 
      from (select t1.col1, t2.col2 
             from table1 t1 
             join table2 t2 on t1.f1=t2.c1) a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I guess I have to mix this with STUFF

Comment: CTE by Giorgos should solve your problem. See result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84757/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking extra effort in producing the result. Yeah Giorgos' appraoch works :)